# Problems about the ideal generated by a set

Tags: ring-theory

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$, a commutative ring with identity. For an element $a\in R$, the ideal generated by the set $I\cup\{a\}$ is denoted by $(I,a)$. Assuming that $a\notin I$, it can be shown that
\begin{equation}
(I,a)=\{i+ra\;|\;i\in I, r\in R\}.
\end{equation}

The problem I have to solve is the following:

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers consider the principal ideals $(n)$ and $(m)$ generated by the integers $n$ and $m$. Using the notation introduced above, verify that 
\begin{equation}
((n),m)=((m),n)=(n)+(m)=(n,m)=(d),
\end{equation}
where $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $m$.

Now, for the first of the four equalities:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
((n),m)=&\{i+rm\;|\;i\in(n), r\in\mathbb{Z}\}\\
=&\{an+rm\;|\;a\in\mathbb{Z}, r\in\mathbb{Z}\}\\
=&\{rm+am\;|\;r\in\mathbb{Z}, a\in\mathbb{Z}\}\\
=&\{j+an\;|\;j\in (m),a\in\mathbb{Z}\}\\
=&((m),n).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Is it correct?

For the other equalities, how could I proceed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line of your equalities corresponds to the definition of the ideal $(n,m)$. For me, the equality $(n)+(m)=(n,m)$ is obvious.

In the last equality (specific to $\mathbf Z$, or more generally to P.I.D.s, $(n,m)\subset (d)$ since clearly, $(n), (m)\subset (d)$. For the reverse inclusion, use *Bézout's identity*.

Comment: @BernardThanks for your anserw, how do I show that $((m),n)=(n)+(m)$?

Comment: Your question shows me I mistyped the ‘obvious formula’: $(n)+(m)=(n,m)$ (without the outer pair of parentheses). So both $((m),n)$ and $(n)+(m)$  are equal to $(n,m)$.